# Block ANY access to ALL servers in our network (Shares, RDP, Web, etc.)

Tags: network-shares, windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

I am creating an AD account for a specific user, we only want that user to be able to access two applications (OWA and another web based) on our network, and not access ANY other machines (RDP, shares, etc.) in any way.

I have way too many servers to go thru all of them and block that user or group, so I need a GP for that user/group to block ALL share access, and any other access to other servers such as other web apps.

I'm assuming I need to leave access to DC for authentication, but that's it.

So to summarize, user can ONLY access:

https://owa
https://someapp

Answer (score 0):

I think your quickest option will be to do a GPO for that user that adds block entries in the Firewall for all services/hosts you don't want them to access.

It'll probably make it easier for you going forward if you have some time later to set up a priveleged user group that you add by default to permissions on shares/etc. and a lower group that will fall under the implicit deny for most AD services.

Comment: the list is too vast for that... can i add a wildcard deny and then an allow for the two sites?

Comment: You can add a general "deny all" and then add specific allow rules. I'm honestly not sure how Windows Firewall handles rule overlaps but hopefully it would be like most permissions where specific overrides general.


Edit: This would probably be messy though and require some testing to make sure everything works. Who is this person that they need more than the 10-15 most common services blocked?

Comment: a consultant is to be only allowed those 2 apps, nothing else on the network, but will be sitting on the regular network.